# deadline counter didnt wotk in real life

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a project that should get a deadline from the user and give time left to the deadline in real life, but I have no idea how to realize it in real life. I also need to use DOM and add this to the local storage.

```
class DeadLine extends  HTMLElement {
    constructor(title,deadline) {
        super();
       this.title=title
        this.deadline=deadline
    }

        connectedCallback() {
            this.deadline = this.getAttribute('deadline')
            this.title = this.getAttribute('title')
            setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000)
            this.update()
        }

        update() {
            let delta = new Date(new Date(this.deadline) - new Date())
            let deltaDay = delta.getDate()-1
            let deltaMinutes = delta.getMinutes()
            let deltaSeconds = delta.getSeconds()
            return[deltaDay,deltaMinutes,deltaSeconds]
            //            let arr=[]
            //             arr.push(deltaDay,deltaMinutes,deltaSeconds)
            //             return arr;
         //    this.innerHTML = `
         // <h2>${ this.title}</h2>
         // <p> ${deltaDay} ${deltaMinutes} ${deltaSeconds}</p>
         // `
        }
 }
 customElements.define('my-deadline',DeadLine)
 deadlineElem.appendChild(newDead)
 btn.addEventListener('click',function (){
     outName.innerText = document.getElementById('titleElem').value
     document.getElementById('titleElem').value = null
     deadlineElem.appendChild(outName.cloneNode(true))
     outTime.innerText = document.getElementById('timeElem').value
     let newTime=document.getElementById('timeElem').value
     let newTitle =document.getElementById('titleElem').value
     document.getElementById('timeElem').value = null
     deadlineElem.appendChild(outTime.cloneNode(true))
     let time1= new DeadLine(newTitle, newTime)
     newDead.innerHTML=time1.update()
     deadlineElem.appendChild(newDead)

 })
 deadlineElem.appendChild(newDead)
```

Comment: Hello gnehgo! I wish you the best on finding an answer. You might have a better reception here if you take time to format your answer in an easy to understand way. If you hope people are going to take time out of their day to offer their expertise free of charge, I would hope you would respect their time by proof reading your post and keeping it somewhat coherent. It might be worth checking out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi gnehgo and welcome to SO. Your question in the current state is incoherent. The question "how do I make this" isn't something that can be answered easily. Please take the time to explain *what doesn't work*, *what it should do*, and *what you've tried to accomplish your goal*. The more time and effort you put in your question, the more time and effort we're able to make to help you solve your issue. And as @asyncawait suggested, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to guide in improving your question.

Answer (score -1):

I've made several modifications to ensure that the countdown is displayed correctly

.1 Storing Deadlines in Local Storage
.2 In your button click event listener, you're creating a DeadLine instance using input values for title and deadline after setting innerText of output elements. This leads to empty input when making the instance.
.3 For countdown display: The update() function calculates days, minutes, seconds, but you're not using the array to update your custom element.

```
 class DeadLine extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    
        connectedCallback() {
            this.title = this.getAttribute('title');
            this.deadline = new Date(this.getAttribute('deadline'));
    
            setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
            this.update();
        }
    
        update() {
            const currentTime = new Date();
            const timeLeft = this.deadline - currentTime;
    
            if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                this.innerHTML = `<h2>${this.title}</h2><p>Time's up!</p>`;
            } else {
                const days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                const hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                const minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                const seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
                this.innerHTML = `
                    <h2>${this.title}</h2>
                    <p>${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds left</p>
                `;
            }
        }
    }
    
    customElements.define('my-deadline', DeadLine);
    
    const btn = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    const deadlineElem = document.getElementById('deadlineContainer');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const newTitle = document.getElementById('titleElem').value;
        const newTime = document.getElementById('timeElem').value;
    
        // Save to local storage if needed
        localStorage.setItem(newTitle, newTime);
    
        const newDead = document.createElement('my-deadline');
        newDead.setAttribute('title', newTitle);
        newDead.setAttribute('deadline', newTime);
    
        deadlineElem.appendChild(newDead);
    });
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.